# Sequelize: Model is not associated to Model2

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I'm trying to make a query with a few models in Sequelize. I have 2 models, one is **Project** and the other one is **Specification**. A project can have many Specifications, and a specification can only belong to one project. The table structure is:

**Project:**

- Title
- Description
- CreatedAt
- UpdatedAt

**Specification:**

- Title
- Description
- ProjectId (Foreign Key from Projects table)

---

This is the relation I have for Specifications -> Projects:

```
Project.belongsToMany(Specification);
```

The function i'm using to retrieve the data is this. Basically it gets all the data, **including all the possible associations**:

```
// Retrieve all Projects from the database.
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
  Project.findAll({
  include: [{
    all: true
  }]
})
.then(data => {
  res.send(data);
})
.catch(err => {
  res.status(500).send({
    message:
      err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving projects."
  });
});
};
```

Finally, the error I'm getting is this:

```
{"message":"specification is not associated to project!"}
```

Can someone help me or teach me about how to accomplish the query? I've been trying and cannot get the right result.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you describe your structure as

> A project can have many Specifications, and a specification can only belong to one project

then it's a usual 1:N relationship and in this case, `hasMany` association should be used instead of `belongsToMany` because `belongsToMany` is used to indicate M:N relationship and in that case, you will need a junction table/model.
That said you only need to replace

```js
Project.belongsToMany(Specification);
```

with

```js
Project.hasMany(Specification, { foreignKey: 'ProjectId' });
```

I always prefer to indicate a foreign key explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasMany` instead of `belongsToMany` to define relation

```
Project.hasMany(Specification, {
  foreignKey: { name: 'ProjectId' },
  targetKey: 'ProjectId',
  constraints: false,
  as: 'specifications',
}),
```